# Redshift: Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Tags: amazon-redshift

Trying to run the following query but getting a message of "Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error". The goal of this is to figure out user engagement based on whether they have sent (messaging_message.sender_id) or received (messaging_subscriber.user_id) a message. Any thoughts on how I could rewrite this query to work? I originally had the subqueries within the case statement but Redshift doesn't allow that yet either.

```
select
    uu.username,
    uu.display_name,
    uu.title,
    (select count(id) from test.messaging_message mm
        where mm.sender_id = uu.id and mm.created > '2021-06-06') as sender,
    (select count(id) from test.messaging_subscriber ms
        where ms.user_id = uu.id and ms.created > '2021-06-06') as recipient,
    case when (sender > 0) or (recipient > 0) then 'yes' else 'no' end as "Engaged"
from
test.users_user uu
where uu.account_id = 126 and uu.is_active = 'true'
limit 10;
```

Comment: Does it work without the „Engaged“ column?

Comment: It does indeed.

Comment: Can you try `case when sender > 0 then 'yes' when (recipient > 0) then 'yes' else 'no' end as "Engaged"`

Comment: Same error unfortunately, @RobertKossendey.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `case when sender > 0 then 'yes' when recipient > 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end as "Engaged"`

Comment: Same error on that one as well. It's certainly not an easy one to work :(

Comment: If Redshift supports subqueries I'd suggest using a subquery to first get all data and then compute the extra column in the outer select.